# How to create tableview cell height separate for parent and child?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have created two different `tableviewcell` into `single tableview`, Now I have set `separate height` for separate `cells` at `storyboard` "row height". Now the problem is whenever I run the application Its not changing both height are same.

Comment: First show us what you did, second there is a delegate method for the UITableView, `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` which you should be using, third you should read through the [UITableViewDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and return different heights for Parent and Child cells.

Sample Implementation :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat height = 0;

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ParentCell"]) {
        height = 100.0; //Parent Cell height
    } else if ([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ChildCell"]) {
        height = 50.0; //Child Cell height
    }

    return height;
}
```

Comment: I need to create for different identifier @Udits

Comment: Do you have custom classes for Parent and child cells or are you simply using UITableViewCell.